# SQLException in Grails save() method

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, grails, jboss

I've a grails (2.2.4) application deployed to a JBoss (5.2) server with DB setup for an Oracle DB:

```
datasource { 
    dbCreate = 'update'
    jndiName = 'java:XXX
}
```

I also have two domain objects:

```
class A {
    def name
    static hasOne = [b:B]
    static constraints = { 
        b unique: true
        name unique: true
    }
}

class B {
    A a
    static belongsTo = [A]
}
```

And finally a service for finding/creating an instance of A:

```
A createA(String name) {
    def a = A.findByName(name)
    if(!a) {
        a = new A(name: name)
        a.b =  new B(a: a)
        a.save() <-- This causes the ERROR. Tried a.save(flush:true), a.save(failOnError:true) and a.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    }
    return a
}
```

When using Hibernates own H2 DB and testing local with both *grails run-app* and *grails run-war* this work fine, but after integrating with the Oracle DB and deploying to JBoss server I get the following error:

```
Hibernate operation: could not execute query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [
    select this_.id as id1_0_, this_.version as version1_0_, this_.name as name1_0_ 
    from a this_ 
    where this_.id=?]; 
SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; 
Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

Anyone got an idea of what is going wrong here?

Comment: The error is generally because the value for `?` wasn't provided. I don't know why it would be there for other DB's and not when you deploy it, but that's what I would start looking into.

Comment: I figured, but since this error is somehow caused by a call down the **save()** method trace I'm not sure how to start debugging it?

Comment: You can log the binding values. Read this article and see if it helps: http://margotskapacs.com/2013/01/log-and-debug-gorm/

Comment: Are you using any 'dialect's in your DataSource.groovy file? If so, make sure they match the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Logging only got me to the same error message, but it's nice feature for future problems. As of dialects I've got none defined in the `DataSource.groovy` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. I had to place the `unique` attributt in the child relation of the `one-to-one` mapping as this:

```
class A {
    def name
    static hasOne = [b:B]
    static constraints = { 
        // b unique: true <-- REMOVED
        name unique: true
    }
}

class B {
    A a
    static belongsTo = [A]
    static constraints = {
        a unique: true // <-- ADDED
    }
}
```

Not really sure why, but it worked.

Comment: It worked because you really can't enforce a unique constraint on hasOne relationship. I am just curious how this is this answer different than mine. I had already provided solution plus more.

Comment: You missed adding the `unique` constraint to the other domain class. Without it, it doesn't look like table `B` get an `unique` constraint on the column `a` and in theory multiple `B` instances could point to same instance of `A`. I think? See this: [link](http://docs.grails.org/2.2.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you can change your domain class, I would make following changes to your domain class.

```
class A {
    def name
    static hasOne = [b:B]
    static constraints = { 
        //b unique: true    // try commenting this line out
        name unique: true   
    }
}

class B {
    A a
    // static belongsTo = [A] // I don't think you need this.
}
```

On your service,

```
A createA(String name) {
    def a = A.findByName(name)
    if(!a) {
        a = new A(name: name).save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
        //a.b =  new B(a: a)  // this feels going around in circles.
        new B(a: a).save(flush:true, failOnError:true)

        // you may only need one save() and the changes will cascade. 
        //I will leave that upto you which save() cascades and which one doesn't.  
    }
    return a
}
```

Also you can look into this http://docs.grails.org/2.3.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrCreateBy.html to simplify your logic.

Comment: Hey, I guess I could simplify but would these modifications still preserve cascading on delete and the actual `one-to-one` relation?

Comment: As long as your belongsTo relationships are properly defined, the cascading should work.